# How can I continue using apt-get on Lubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, updates, versions, support

Today apt-get has stopped working on my Lubuntu 16.10. Whenever I try to install packages using apt-get install  nothing happens after "reading packages list" has been printed out.

I guess that is due to end of support for that version of Ubuntu, but I am happy with using this system and would like to avoid reinstallation, if possible.

Edit: I've already seen the question for which mine has been marked as a duplicate and it didn't solve my problem (after executing the command given as the solution only a message about the package not being found is getting printed out).

Comment: Please use a supported release to get support here. 16.10 is no longer supported.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you didn't type the command correctly. When I was using Ubuntu 10.10 after its EOL, I executed this command on a terminal and it worked.

Copy and paste this command on a Terminal window:

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, update the repositories using this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

***NOTE:*** When you want to execute a command described in a Ask Ubuntu post, you should better copy and paste it. If you do not do that, you may encounter some issues by the mistyped command, or the command might not work at all.

Comment: It simply does not work as described in the edit (and ofc I've copy-pasted it).

Comment: Please use a supported release to get support here. 10.10 or 16.10 are no longer supported.